# Angular user directive not working

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am loading directive 'user' in-app module. I want to alert hello world when someone clicks user. Its working like charm in the home controller but it not working in category controller.
 
Can you please tell me How can I resolve this issue? And why this issue is happening? Please note there is no any error in category module nor in any other module.

Directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Directive({
  selector: '[user]' // Attribute selector
})
export class UserDirective {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController) {
  }

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    alert('Hello world!);
  }

}
```

App module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule, IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { UserDirective } from '../directives/user/user';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    UserDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Controller:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the CategoriesPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-categories',
  templateUrl: 'categories.html',
})
export class CategoriesPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CategoriesPage');
  }

}
```

View:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="segment" color="primary" *ngIf="this.Loader != 1">
  <ion-segment-button value="Home" (click)="page_redirect('HomePage')" text-center>
    Home
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="Featured" (click)="page_redirect('FeaturedItemPage')" text-center>
    Featured
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="Category" (click)="page_redirect('CategoriesPage')" text-center>
    Category
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="User" user text-center>
    User
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

Comment: Use something like console.log to verify and not alert since those can be suppressed by the user in the browser. Otherwise, your code looks ok, so without any other details I would assume ion-segment-button may be preventing click event for progating or something.

Comment: @Aleski It working fine in Homepage but not working in the category page. and U checked main.js code is loading IDK why this happening.